# How to run postdeploy scripts in heroku button app.json

Tags: heroku

I tried to setup Heroku Button which my app required several post deploy scripts. Don't know how to put it in next to each.

Here my app.json

```
{
  "name": "App on Heroku",
  "description": "The App deployable to Heroku.",
  "keywords": [
    "App",
    "Heroku"
  ],
  "repository": "https://github.com/myaccount/myapp",
  "logo": "http://node-js-sample.herokuapp.com/node.svg",
  "addons": [
    "heroku-postgresql",
    "postmark"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "postdeploy": [
        "bundle exec rake db:migrate",
        "bundle exec rake db:seed",
        "bundle exec my_sample:load"
       ]
  }
}
```

Here error message at

**Run scripts & scale dynos**

Postdeploy exit code was not 0

```
bash: ((: bundle exec rake db:migrate,bundle exec rake db:seed,bundle exec my_sample:load: syntax error in expression (error token is "exec rake db:migrate,bundle exec rake db:seed,bundle exec my_sample:load")
```

Comment: I don't think you can run multiple scripts

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me :

1. Create a bash/sh script called `myscript.sh` in the same directory as your app.json file (normally, this should be your root directory).
2. Place all your commands in that file the same way you would call them in your terminal.
3. Reference the script in your app.json file (see below how)
4. Make sure your script has the correct permissions. Preferably, run `chmod +x myscript.sh`.

My **app.json** file :

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "postdeploy": "./myscript.sh"
  }
}
```

The **myscript.sh** file :

```
#!/bin/sh

bundle exec rake db:migrate
bundle exec rake db:seed
bundle exec my_sample:load
```

Comment: Thanks.. I was able to make something similar and it worked..   using "sh heroku_postdeploy_script.sh" and then a simple .sh file, I did not need the #!/bin/sh bit.

Answer (score 4):

I found this googling other issues, but think this documentation is relevant 
- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/release-phase#review-apps-and-the-postdeploy-script

**To apply that documentatation and answer your question:**

Separate your schema setup from your data loading by running the `db:migrate` command in your Heroku Procfile with this command:

`release: bundle exec rake db:migrate`

And then keep your other `postdeploy` steps in the `app.json` file.

````
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "postdeploy": "bundle exec rake db:seed && bundle exec rake my_sample:load"
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 2):

Should be able to do this (dokku example but same goes for heroku):

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "dokku": {
      "predeploy": "bundle exec rake db:migrate && bundle exec rake some:task"
    }
  }
}
```